# Java String remove all non numeric characters and word like var123

Tags: java, string, character

I have a String:

```
String s = "12 text var2 14 8v 1";
```

I need to get only numbers from this string like:

```
12 14 1.
```

But I don't need words like:

```
var2 and 8v.c
```

I tried this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");`
```

Comment: how can i get only string like: 12 14 1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17516067/2290235

Comment: Do you want the numbers as a String? i.e String result = "12 14 1"? or in an array etc?

Comment: @xgeorgekx, yes like a String result = "12 14 1"

Comment: @GlobalBubble Please accept an answer. People want their points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `String.replaceAll` for this, there's a workaround:

```
//            | one or more non-digits
//            |   | followed by one or more digits
//            |   |   | followed by one or more non-digits
//            |   |   |    | or the end of the input      
//            |   |   |    |     | replace with single white space
s.replaceAll("\\D+\\d+(\\D+|$)", " ");
```

**Output**

```
12 14 1
```

However, this solution is ugly and might break with different inputs.

I recommend you parse for positives instead, and gather by iterating over input.

Something in the lines of:

```
//                           | word boundary
//                           |  | one or more digits
//                           |  |    | word boundary
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+\\b");
```

Comment: could you please explain how the first example might break?

Comment: @MichałSchielmann well I just edited my answer, because adding a non-digit+ followed by digit+ item at the end of the input would break the solution - i.e. if input was `"12 text var2 14 8v 1 a1"`. I don't have a clearer picture of further edge cases, only that it looks tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is word boundaries (`\b`). This seems to work:

```
String s = "x4 12 text var2 14 8v 1 1a";
s = s.replaceAll("\\b[\\d.]*[^ \\d.]+[\\d.]*\\b", "").replaceAll("  +", " ").trim();
System.out.println(s); // "12 14 1"
```

What that does is look for word boundaries on either side of anything that has at least one non-digit, non-decimal-point, non-space in it, and removes the entire match. You may need to add more that just spaces to the negated character class in the middle, depending on your input. Then I trim extraneous spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Other Solution with `Guava` And `Apache Common`

```
String s = "12 text var2 14 8v 1";
Iterable<String> split = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.BREAKING_WHITESPACE).split(s);

for (String string : split) {
    boolean isNumber = StringUtils.isNumber(string);
    if(isNumber) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

// Result -- 12 14 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Scanner` class to scan every word in the sentence and a method that you pass each word and checks if its a number or not.

```
static boolean isNumber(String a){
    try{
        int x = Integer.parseInt(a);  
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){  
        return false; // if it attempts to parse an int from a String like "text" etc..
    }  
    return true;  // if int was successfully parsed 
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    String s = "12 text var2 14 8v 1"; 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
    String result = "";

    while(in.hasNext()){ //scan every word
        String a = in.next();
            if(isNumber(a)) //check if number
                result += a + " "; //add only if its number
    }

    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);//do this to remove the last " "(space) added inside the loop
}
```

`System.out.println(result);` will print: `"12 14 1"`

Answer (score -1):

Try this [regex](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html):

```
([0-9]*[^0-9\s]+[0-9]*\s*)
```

Here all strings that have(or have not) digit at begining `[0-9]*` that is followed by one or more non-digit character `[^0-9\s]+` and then have (or have not) a digit and space `[0-9]*\s*` are found.
It will find all characters but numbers. It works for all kind of characters - also special characters.

Using it this way would result in what you need:

```
String myString = "12 text var2 14 8v 1";
myString = myString.replaceAll("([0-9]*[^0-9\\s]+[0-9]*\\s*)", "");
System.out.println(myString);
```

Output:

```
12 14 1
```

Comment: Not what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Mena Ok, my bad - I must have not read it correctly or the question was changed. I'll edit.

Comment: Basically what OP wants is to leave only digit-only sequences of 1+ digits.

Comment: No problems! Just FYI I haven't downvoted the answer. Someone else did.

Comment: @Mena - np. The downvote is understandable as it was not correct, so whoever did vote was right. Glad I could figure that out, but frankly your solution seems simpler ;)