# Extracting signs/symbols from a string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string with signs and i want to get the signs only and put them in a string array, here is what I've done:

```
String str = "155+40-5+6";

// replace the numbers with spaces, leaving the signs and spaces
String signString = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", " ");

// then get an array that contains the signs without spaces
String[] signsArray = stringSigns.trim().split(" ");
```

However the the 2nd element of the signsArray is a space, [+ ,   , -, +]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516049/java-removing-numeric-values-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this a couple of ways.  Either replace multiple adjacent digits with a single space:

```
// replace the numbers with spaces, leaving the signs and spaces
String signString = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+", " ");
```

Or alternatively in the last step, split on multiple spaces:

```
// then get an array that contains the signs without spaces
String[] signsArray = signString.trim().split(" +");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `" "` to `""` in your code

```
String str = "155+40-5+6";

// replace the numbers with spaces, leaving the signs and spaces
String signString = str.replaceAll("[0-9]","");

// then get an array that contains the signs without spaces
String[] signsArray = stringSigns.split("");
```

This should work for you. Cheers

Image of running code
[image]

Comment: It doesn't, but using:   str.replaceAll("[^+-]+", " ");   or    str.replaceAll("[0-9]+", " "); does, thanks for your help :)

Comment: it worked for me, i have attached image also ..anyways your problem solved