# How do i remove digits from a String

Tags: java

Basically my questions is how can i remove the digits from a string that is being inputted Thanks for helping me as well

## Example:

### Input

700N

### Output:

N

Comment: Naive approach: loop over every character of the string. If it is not a number, add it to the result string.

Comment: Or maybe this? [Java: removing numeric values from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516049/java-removing-numeric-values-from-string)

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.replaceAll()` method:

```
str.replaceAll("[0123456789]","");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use replaceAll

```
    String st1 = "700N";
    st1 = st1.replaceAll("\\d+", "");
    System.out.println(st1);
```

**output**

```
N
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way I could come up with :

```
String input ="700N";
String output= input.replaceAll("\\d","");
```

The regex `\\d` means digit.