# How to create a method that removes alphabet only in a String

Tags: java, arrays

```
myString = "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19."
```

I'm calling `myString.remove("ra6")`, and this should return `"my lucky numbes e 6, 8, nd 19"`.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

```
public String remove(String arg) {
    if (myString != null) {
        char[] arrayOfChars1 = myString.toCharArray();
        char[] arrayOfChars2 = arg.toCharArray();
        char[] newArray = 
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm trying to create an `arrayOfChars1` so that I can compare it to the given String which would be another `arrayOfChars2`.

and a third array to store the comparison. If a char is in both array (`arrayOfChar1 and arrayOfChar2`) is found it should be removed but only the alphabets not numbers.

```
myString = "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19."
myString.remove("ra6") //6 should be ignored.

return "my lucky numbe(r)s (a)(r)e 6, 8, and 19."
```

only char 'a' and 'r' should be removed

Comment: Please explain why that is the expected output.

Comment: Use `replaceAll` using a character class containing those characters: `"[ra6]"`. Replace them all with nothing: `""`

Comment: only the alphabet should be removed if I use replaceAll even then numbers will be replaced

Comment: Remove the number from the argument first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516049/java-removing-numeric-values-from-string

Answer (score 2):

You can first remove all non letter characters from the String of characters to replace and use `String#replaceAll` with a character class.

```
String s = "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19.";
String remove = "ra6";
String res = s.replaceAll("["+
      remove.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")
     +"]", "");
System.out.println(res);
```

> only char 'a' and 'r' should be removed

You can replace the regex, `[ar]` with `""`. The regex, `[ar]` means one of the characters inside the square bracket and is known as [Character Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html).

```
String myString = "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19.";
myString = myString.replaceAll("[ar]", "");
System.out.println(myString);// my lucky numbes e 6, 8, nd 19.
```